# Maven pointing to the wrong directory of JDK

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm facing a strange problem when trying to run clean and install on maven. I get the following error message:

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.CompilerException: tools.jar not found: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\..\lib\tools.jar
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.createJavacClass(JavacCompiler.java:987)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.getJavacClass(JavacCompiler.java:944)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.compileInProcess(JavacCompiler.java:520)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.compile(JavacCompiler.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:678)
    ... 14 more
```

I looked for common causes of this issue and most of them says that the problem must be that I need to point a JDK in my installed JRE's (and in the error message I see that it is actually pointing a JRE). But when I check my installed JRE's it is pointing to a JDK:

[image]

Java Home is set here:

[image]

Any ideas of what may be causing this error?

Comment: You are using a JRE and NOT a JDK...What's in your IDE does not matter. Are you trying to run from your IDE or from command line?

Comment: From IDE. It was working and suddenly it broke somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the JRE, you need to set your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to the JDK path.

Comment: Hi drJava. I've just posted my JDK Java Home configuration... isn't it right?

Answer (score 0):

Did you change your `PATH` from the time when it was working? When you do `mvn clean install` from command line, Maven delegates the build of Java sources to `javac` found in the `PATH`. A quick check would be to set the `PATH` as `set PATH="<path-to-jdk\bin>;<rest>"` and retry `mvn clean install`.